# How to multiply small numbers in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, awk

I want to multiply all entries in a array with numbers like `3.17 * 10^-7`, but Bash can't do that. I tried with `awk` and `bc`, but it doesn't work. I would be obliged if someone can help me.

Input data example (overall 4000 datafile):

```
TecN210500-0100.plt
TecN210500-0200.plt
TecN210500-0300.plt
TecN210500-0400.plt
......
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

ZS=($(find . -name "*.plt")) 
i=1

Variable=$(awk "BEGIN{print 10 ** -7}")
Solutiontime=$(awk "BEGIN{print 3.17 * $Variable}")

for Dataname in ${ZS[@]}
do
    Cut=${Dataname:13}
    Timesteps=${Cut:0:${#Cut}-4}
    Array[i]=$Timesteps 
    i=$((i++))
    p=$((i++))
done

Amount=$p

for ((i=1;i<10;i++))
do
    Array[i]=${i}00
done

for (($i=1;i<$Amount+1;i++))
do
    Array[i]=$(awk "BEGIN{print ${Array[i]} * $Solutiontime}")
done

Array[0]=Solutiontime
```

First loop:
Extract e.i. the "0100".

Second loop:
"Delete" the leading zero -> e.i. "100"

Last loop:
Multiply with time step -> e.i. "100 * 3.17*10^-7"

Comment: Nope, man, this code is illegible. Please improve formatting by indenting it _with four spaces_. Also see [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: This will never increment $i: `i=$((i++))` -- because you're using the **post**-increment operator, the return value is the **previous** value of `i` to assign to `i`. `++` is already an assignment operator, just stick with `((i++)); p=$i`

Comment: Thanks for your advice!

Comment: So are you just looking for output based on the name of the file `TecN210500-0100.plt`, not reading anything from the file?

Comment: Yes, it's only about the filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a little [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) trimming on the filename, and then let `awk` do the math for you.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.plt; do
    num=${f##*-}   # remove the stuff before the final -
    num=${num%.*}  # remove the stuff before the last .
    num=${num#0}   # remove the left-hand zero
    awk "BEGIN {print $num * 3.17 * 10**-7}"
done
```

Or, done entirely with `awk`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.plt; do
    awk -v f="$f" 'BEGIN {gsub(/^TecN[[:digit:]]+-0?|.plt$/, "", f); print f  * 3.17 * 10**-7}'
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That works fine. How can I save every step into a file without overwriting the last step?

Comment: I got it: `awk "BEGIN {print $num * 3.17 * 10**-7}" >> File.txt` If I need further information, it would be great ask again.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk 'BEGIN{print 3.17 * 10^-7 }'

3.17e-07
```

iteration 1

```
awk -F'[-.]' '{printf "%s %e\n",substr($1,5),$2*3.17*10^-7}' file

210500 3.170000e-05
210500 6.340000e-05
210500 9.510000e-05
210500 1.268000e-04
```

for the posted file names used as input.

iteration 2

If you need just the computed numbers, simple drop the first field

```
awk -F'[-.]' '{printf "%e\n",$2*3.17*10^-7}' file

3.170000e-05
6.340000e-05
9.510000e-05
1.268000e-04
```

this will be the output of the script.  I strongly suggest moving whatever logic you have inside the `awk` script rather than working on shell level with the array.

Comment: If I do that, the entries of the array are strange. e.i. 300 1,7e-06. On this position it should be 3.17e-05 because the operation is 100*3,17*10^-7.

Comment: please post a representative input data in your original post.  Otherwise it's guesswork.  Your original question was how to multiple `3.17 * 10^-7` which what I have shown.

Comment: I have exported datafile from the fluid dynamic program "fluent". The filename are "TecN210500-xxxxx.plt". "xxxxx" are the iteration steps. The First loop extract the iteration steps from the filename. But the first 9 datafile are "TecN210500-0100.plt"; "TecN210500-0200.plt" ..... so the leading zero must delete. The second loop delete the leading zero. The last loop multiply every iteration number with the time step. The result will be the solution time. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: I'm not claiming it's the answer but is this what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't understand your posted code but yes, that's what I trying to achieve... I would be appreciative if you can show me how to implement this in my code. I want this in a array without the leading number 210500.

Comment: I use bash since yesterday 10 am. My skill level are very small. Actually I want to write the entries of the array into the input file. Unfortunately I don't really understand what you mean. Do you think working with shell is better than using awk script? I've got no experience with shell. Technically I only want multiply the iteration numbers with the time step and write the result into a array.

Comment: just the opposite.  I just showed how powerful `awk` can be.  The output can be redirected to a file, i.e  `awk ... inputfile > outputfile` so the result will be in the outputfile.  If you're going to do something with the computed numbers still easier to do in `awk`

Comment: Your posted code looks very easy. But awk is very difficult for loan. With `awk -F'[-.]' '{printf "%e\n",$2*3.17*10^-7}' file` I read in "file" the input. But in my case, the "input" are the filenames. How could I implement that? Something like "ZS" and the first loop in my code.

Comment: `find . -name "*.plt" > inputfile` and the rest follows

Comment: Do you mean like this: `#!/bin/bash
find . -name "*.plt" > File
awk -F'[-.]' '{printf "%e\n",$2*3.17*10^-7}' File`. If I do that, only 0,000000e+00 is shown.